# How to model a set of integer variables getting assigned different values than another set of integer variables

Tags: modeling, constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

Assume we have variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ that each can belong to $\{1,2,...,10\}$. How can we model a constraint that variables $x_1, x_2$ get assigned **different** values than $x_3, x_4$?

Because of scaling issue, it is not efficient to enumerate all assignment combinations as $\\x_1 \neq x_3, \quad x_1 \neq x_4, \quad x_2 \neq x_3, \quad x_2 \neq x_4$.

I am using OR-Tools CP-SAT.

Comment: Is (1, 3) and (1, 4) OK ?

Comment: Since $x_1=x_3$ it is not allowed, @LaurentPerron. $(x_1=1, x_2=1) and (x_3=3, x_4=4)$ is allowed though.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean $(x_1,x_2)\not=(x_3,x_4)$, you can enforce this with:
$$10(x_1-1) + (x_2-1) \not= 10(x_3-1)+(x_4-1)$$
Equivalently:
$$10x_1 + x_2 \not= 10x_3+x_4 \tag1$$

---

If instead you meant the four disequalities you listed,
you can impose $$(x_1 - x_3)(x_1 - x_4)(x_2 - x_3)(x_2 - x_4)\not=0$$
Alternatively,
you might consider generating your four disequalities dynamically only if they are violated.  In this case, $(1)$ is still valid but is only a relaxation.

---

Here's a MILP formulation.  Let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether $x_i=j$, and let binary variable $z_{g,j}$ indicate whether any variable in group $g$ is assigned value $j$.  Then your constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_j y_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,1000\}$} \\
\sum_j j y_{i,j} &= x_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,1000\}$} \\
y_{i,j} &\le z_{g,j} &&\text{for $g\in\{1,2\}$, $i$ in group $g$, and $j\in\{1,\dots,10\}$} \\
\sum_g z_{g,j} &\le 1 &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,10\}$}
\end{align}

Comment: The product is catastrophically slow.

Comment: If you want the product to be != 0, just add that all 4 differences are != 0.

Comment: Indeed, reformulating as one big product constraint does not help much in the context of a CP (or CP-SAT) solver. Moreover, this reformulation also leads to a quadratic number of terms to create.

Comment: Correct, I was hoping it can be modeled using what's available in constraint programming.

Comment: I do not understand the scalability problem. Is it in the number of variables, or the number of values, or both ? I recommend reading https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md and going back to Boolean logic as soon as possible.

Comment: For instance, if we have 1000 integers variables in group 1 and 1000 integer variables in group 2, $x_i \neq x_j, \quad i\in G_1, j\in G_2$ would be 1,000,000 constraint. However, if we could somehow assign in order and once we are done with all in group 1, we could black list those in group two, it could be better. As an MILP this is hard to implement since value of the variables only realized after the model is solved. However, I thought with constraint propagation idea in CP, there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: In your real problem, do you have only two groups of variables, are the values $\{1,\dots,10\}$, and do you care how the values are split up between the groups? For example, would it be OK for group 1 to use 9 values and group 2 to use the remaining 1 value? Or would you want them evenly split 5 and 5?

Comment: Correct, there is only two groups of variables. Same number can be assigned to multiple variables in the same group but any number is not allowed to be assigned to variables in more than one group. There are other constraints in the problem that affect the assignment so it is important to make no assumption about structure of optimal solution.

Comment: @Mahmoud I added a MILP formulation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @RobPratt. Your MILP is correct. However, it needs $|V| \times |S| + |G| \times |S|$ binary variables which require branching in MILP. This is while there are $|V_{G_1}| \times |V_{G_2}|$ (or $ |S|^2/4$) using CP.

Comment: @Mahmoud $|V|<<|S|$ and $|G|<<|S|$, so the constraint count favors MILP.  Also, $z$ will automatically be integer when $y$ is.  I would expect MILP to perform better than CP here, but you can't really tell without trying both.

Comment: CP-SAT is a mip solver. If you use a Boolean formulation, I would expect it would perform nicely.

Comment: The number of constraints is generally not a reliable indicator of the hardness of a mathematical model, whatever the solver used. Without testing, this is almost impossible to claim what will perform best here.